# How to rename the users column in WordPress database

Tags: wordpress

I have this specific requirement using shared database which is shared by laravel. In the db table, all the registered username records gets stored in **'username'** column (under users table), so I need to retrieve the username to login in another app that is built in WordPress. By default WordPress retrieve username from **'user_login'** column, so what I am looking here is pick username from **'username'** column instead of **'user_login'**.. This is how I am trying to filter

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'so_25737835' );

function so_25737835( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['user_login'] = 'username';
    return $columns;
}
```

If anyone has something to share then it will be nice.

Comment: Quote docs, _“`manage_users_columns` is a filter applied to the columns **on the manage users screen**.”_ - so that’s likely not going to help at all here. _“I have this specific requirement using shared database which is shared by laravel”_ - sounds like a _very bad_ approach to begin with. This should probably be done by implementing a proper “bridge” between the two systems - instead of letting them poke around the same database table.

Comment: i think best way is a mapping table to sync users